# Emacs Dired: weird behavior of `dired-dwim-target`

Tags: emacs, dired

The behavior I have is odd at best, but the situation is simple: given a folder `test`, I want to make a copy of it in another folder.

In practice:

- Open Emacs, <kbd>M-x dired</kbd> in any folder.
- <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>test</kbd> to create a folder `test`.
- <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>target</kbd> to create a folder `target`.
- Move on `test` then <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>target/</kbd> to copy it in `target`.

So far so good, the empty `test` folder is copied as expected. Assuming there is some change in this folder, we want to copy it again to the same place:

- Move on `test` then <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>target/</kbd> to copy it in `target`.
- Dired asks for confirmation to overwrite it, and if `yes` copies it again.

Now the weird behavior. With `(setq dired-dwim-target t)`:

- Open a second window <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>
- Move to `target` in this window, as to have `target` on the right window, but the initial folder on the left window.
- In the left window, move on `test` and <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it again, DWIM will suggest directly `target/`, so all that is needed is <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note that there is no question to overwrite it or not. Visiting `target` now shows the `test` folder, but inside it a second copy of `test`!

Even weirder:

- Create an empty file in the original folder (<kbd>C-x C-f</kbd><kbd>bla</kbd>, then <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to save it, and <kbd>C-x k</kbd> to kill it).
- Select in the left window both `test` and `bla` with <kbd>m</kbd>.
- <kbd>C</kbd> to copy them, DWIM will suggest directly `target/`, so all that is needed is <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now it asks for confirmation and copies `test` together with `bla` in `target` as expected!

What am I missing?

(of course, this example mostly uses empty folders, but that's really just for the demonstration.)

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: I just did. Let's see how it goes!

Comment: The bug is #[25609](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25609).

Comment: And is now [closed in master branch](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25609#25)!